# A beginner question for Modulo with exponentiation calculation

Tags: python, python-3.x, modulo, exponentiation

The question is below but how is it calculated in Py and what command should I be entering in Py?
Suppose you have $100, which you can invest with a 10% return each year. After one year, it's 100×1.1=110 dollars, and after two years it's 100×1.1×1.1=121.  how much money you end up with after 7 years.

Please help.

Thanks to all who answer.

Comment: what is your question??? I do not see any question.

Comment: Sorry, what does this have to do with modulo? Your question is very unclear...

Comment: Hello John, is your question `how to compute 100 x 1.1^7 with python`? Could you be more precise and add an example?

Comment: What does *"5,390 when 4**2 is 16"* have to do with this, please edit your question and delete all irrelevant stuff like that.

Comment: Can you please clarify your problem? Calculating ``100 * 1.1 ** 7`` in Python gives the correct ``194.87``.  The $770 stated in the question is not correct.

Comment: Edited my question. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the precedence of the `**` operator is more than the `*` operator. Hence your your statement becomes `100 * (1.1 ** 7)` and the answer is `194.87171000000012`.

You can refer to https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/operators_precedence_example.htm for more information on operator precedence in Python.

Comment: Edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this, but the other answer is better code:

```py
i = 0
sum = 100
while i < 7:
   sum = sum * 1.1
   i += i
```